# Should I answer questions which contain "copy-paste" problem?

Tags: discussion, answers

On September the 1st, 2015, I encountered the following question (google-maps):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329689/google-maps-marker-push-infowindow#comment52538959_32329689

At first, I thought it was a nice question to answer (although the amount of code given). I requested a demo of the code so that I can make an easier edit and give an appropriate solution. The OP provided a fiddle but the fiddle was poorly constructed and showed minimal effort from the OP.

Although I didn't really care about the poor offered fiddle, after few minutes I noticed that the question was actually a copy and paste solution taken from two URL's:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details

To avoid expanding this question further, I wrote a comment on the question (google-maps), explaining which steps should be taken by the OP in order to make it better (although many more would be required for a better question).

This is not the first time I came to such "copy-paste" problem which demands rearranging the code from SO solvers in order to make it work.

Should such question's be treated like more sophisticated types of homework which have the code copy and pasted from a source and the other code (copy-pasted as well) inserted into it just to show that they "did something more" or are they treated as legitimate questions which can be answered?

Comment: Downvote for no demonstrated effort, and vote to close as "Off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Comment: I have noticed a tendency to 'iterate solutions' by copy-pasting answers to previous questions too. I don't have much patience for those, unless they're quite clearly improving in understanding, rather than trying to sneak a 'write my code for me' request through.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends but generally speaking I would say no.

The core principle of questions and answers here is to be a knowledgebase. As a consequence the answer is not as much important for the OP but it should be much more targeted at future visitors.

With that in mind, you assess the question by wondering if anybody else is going to run into the same/similar problem. If the answer is *No* then you have a couple of options:

- down vote: not useful or unclear is a valid reason to down vote questions
- Close vote / flag: Use the reason Unclear/ too broad or off-topic, needs MCVE
- comment: to get the OP to clarify the real issue, errors, unexpected behavior
- edit: **ONLY** If you see fit / understand the mistake / the wrong turn made by the OP to salvage the question so it becomes worth keeping it around. Not something that is easy to do if you're below 2K because that often needs a significant rewrite and that doesn't go well with reviewers.

You can answer the question in cases where the OP clearly state that they try to combine an example from X and an example from Y but they run into an error/issue where the error/issue should be clearly stated. I assume X and Y can be reasonably combined in this case.

The last case is useful to answer because future visitors might want to try that same path. Having an answer that explains how you can bring two examples/technologies/frameworks together is useful for future visitors.

Comment: Basically I agree with the answer of @Rene, however for: "edit: If you see fit / understand the mistake / the wrong turn made by the OP to salvage the question" I think it's not a good approach. 
Generally there is very few effort made to write these questions, editing them would probably need even more effort than answering them. Also those questions are generally very specific and I often have the filling that OP doesn't even know programming just posts something he received / googled / inherited and ask us to fix it (basically the same effort from him than asking for code from scratch).

Comment: @MátéJuhász if question is *useful and unique* than effort of editing it into shape may worth it (maybe on case in thousand so).

Comment: That might be true and I slightly edited the answer to reflect that but we do have the H&I queue that basically is aiming for these kind of gems to let them shine. I admit that editing those is a huge effort sometimes similar to writing a good answer. If the question isn't deleted/closed it should be up to par to prevent this site becomes like many, many forums out in the interwebz with their often incomprehensible posts that no one can edit.